# Access JSON response before RestKit maps it

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I am using an API that prepends `)]}'` to every JSON response, apparently as a safety measure. e.g.

```
response.body=)]}',
[{"id":13,"name":"Demo Company","total_amount_due":15714.2}]
```

RestKit can't map that, so I need to strip the first item from the response before mapping.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: the issue was more with accessing the response before RestKit tried to map it

Comment: How is that a safety measure? Safety against what?

Comment: Not sure. I thought it strange myself.

Comment: @Wain It's a measure against cross site scripting and other illegitimate access patterns. By making the JSON invalid without knowing ahead of time how to make it valid, unauthorized users have a much harder time interpreting the input. Of course it's pretty easy to work around once you see the raw string. But it prevents a lot of automated attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by making a `MyJsonSerialization` class:

```
@interface MyJsonSerialization : NSObject <RKSerialization>

@end


@implementation MyJsonSerialization

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSString* responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *refinedData = data;

    if ([responseStr hasPrefix:@")]}',"]){
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(5, data.length - 5);
        refinedData = [data subdataWithRange:range];
    }

    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:refinedData options:0 error:error];

    return result;
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:error];
}

@end
```

And using it like this:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[MyJsonSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```